# Missing folders, where else should I look

Tags: filesystems, rhel, mount

When I first configured a server I created a set of folders and an additional drive. Today it was reported that these folders are now missing. After looking through /log/messages I see this line, which is different than a similar server that was patched on the same night.

```
systemd: u01.mount: Directory /u01 to mount over is not empty, mounting anyway.
```

One fix suggested `umount` then `mount` to recover data. There was no change, and the only folder under the mountpoint is the `lost+found` which is empty.

I'm looking for any additional troubleshooting steps to see if the files/folders could be recovered.

Comment: The sequence you followed is a little confusing; are you saying that the directory was empty *after* mounting `/u01`, or while `/u01` was *unmounted*?  It sounds like, from the first message, that your data is underneath the current `/u01` mount.

Comment: What it appears to have happened, may missed something in troubleshooting, is 
1 server configured, including folder structure
2 after months in operation server was patched and rebooted
3 during boot that error is generated
4 report of files missing
5 troubleshooting, including unmount/mount, no new log messages
I only assume the original files are somehow "under" the existing blank mount point.